# When executing a command, it is automatically suspended

Tags: linux, bash, job-control

The problem happened on one of my local machines with CentOS 6. I ssh to it from my MacBook trying to test a script, which is in /usr/local/bin. However, whenever I tried to execute the command, it is immediately suspended, displaying "[1]+  Stopped". I had to use `fg` to make it the foreground. Since it's 3 a.m. in the morning, I was wondering if it is related to nice. But I tried some command with nice and renice, it didn't work. As the script calls an I/O-bound Perl script, I also tried ionice but it didn't work either.

It seems difficult to reproduce the problem, since after a reboot the problem is gone. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Sounds like the script you're running has a line in it that's getting backgrounded. Look for a line that has an ampersand at the end of it, `&`.

Comment: No, I didn't use any ampersands in my script. My script simply calls the Perl script. When I executed the Perl script, or even `wget`, the same thing happened.

Comment: Please share your script, if possible, also I'd take a look at the settings for your shell, specifically the `shopt` command to see if you've accidentally enabled a unusual mode.

Comment: @slm This is the script [yaanyap](https://github.com/shichao-an/yaanyap/blob/master/yaanyap), `shopt` output [link](https://gist.github.com/shichao-an/9521450) and `set -o` output. [link](https://gist.github.com/shichao-an/9521462). Because after the reboot the problem was gone , the options may not be exactly the same as the issue occurred, though I remembered I didn't accidentally enable any mode.

Comment: @slm  I just use URLs from YouTube.

Comment: Any YouTube link will work. Make sure you use the latest GitHub repo of get_flash_videos. The official release does not work mostly.

Comment: I was able to download the trunk ver. from github and have been using it for several days and it hasn't demonstrated this issue a single time. Is there anything else you can describe to help characterize this problem? I D/L'd it from here: https://github.com/monsieurvideo/get-flash-videos

Comment: What locale is your system set to? `locale`. Perhaps one of the tools is not able to work with a different character set?

Answer (score 0):

The process is asking for something from the standard input.  When a background task needs to read standard input, the task is stopped.  Let's take a simple example:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat | awk '{print ++linenum " " $0}'
```

Now, let's call this `linenum.sh` and run it in the background of a Bash script:

```
sh ./linenum.sh &
```

What happens?

```
[1] Stopped sh ./linenum.sh
```

Why is it stopped?  Because it needs standard input to continue.

So, how do we stop the annoying `Stopped` message?  By giving it something in the standard input!

```
cat /dev/null | sh ./linenum.sh &
```

This particular script will immediately terminate (since `/dev/null` is a 0-length file with read)

Comment: My script does not ask for stdin. Neither does the Perl script. I think the problem is something related to the system, since before the reboot, the Perl script or even `wget` was suspended.